# Chinese text not show using dompdf

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3, dompdf, cjk

Hello i want to convert html to pdf using dompdf, my HTML has Chinese text. In HTML view the Chinese text show very well, but when I convert to pdf the Chinese text only show square.

This is my code

```
$html = $this->load->view('view_view', $data, TRUE);
//echo $html;

require("assets/dompdf1/autoload.inc.php"); 
define("DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED", true);
$options = new Options();
$options->set('defaultFont', 'DejaVu Sans');
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);


// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

        // Output the generated PDF to Browser

$dompdf->stream("View.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));


exit(0);
```

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsJA5.png)

I already set the font face in the HTML

```
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<style>
    @page {
        margin-top: 0.3cm;
        margin-bottom: 0cm;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'NotoSansCJK';
        src: url('assets/dompdf1/lib/fonts/NotoSansCJKtc-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    }
     body {
       font-family: 'NotoSansCJK', DejaVu Sans, sans-serif;
    }
    </style>
```

Can someone help me, I already searching anywhere but still don't find the solution

I use dompdf ver 0.8.0

EDIT: I follow chams by adding the line

```
$options = new Options();
$options->set('defaultFont', 'DejaVu Sans');
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
```

and the square is gone, I don't know what is wrong
[Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW7lT.png)

EDIT: I just update the font, I'm using kai bold font, the square is coming back [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmRv7.png)

EDIT: I just update the font again, I'm using NotoSansCJKtc-Regular, and still got the square.

EDIT: I follow this https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2773 and now works fine

[font folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuNkA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to a font that support Chinese characters which Dompdf by default don't support.

EDIT:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
define('DOMPDF_FONT_DIR', __DIR__ . 'path-to-fonts-dir');

$options = new Options();
$options->set('isPhpEnabled', true); // Enable PHP evaluation
$options->set('fontDir', DOMPDF_FONT_DIR);
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);

$html = $this->load->view('view_view', $data, TRUE);
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');

$options->set('defaultFont', 'NotoSansCJKtc-Regular');

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("View.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));

exit(0);
```

Comment: yes, i already use the font that support chinese character, I just edit my question.

Comment: please check https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#about-fonts--character-encoding

Comment: i already follow the guide but still have same problem, I don't know why

Comment: look at the question, i just edit it, i don't know what is wrong

Comment: i checked your edit, now we confirmed that's a font problem please try to use NotoSansCJKtc-Regular

Comment: ok i wll try it

Comment: Sorry i already try it but still error, check my edit.

Comment: $options->set('defaultFont', 'NotoSansCJKtc-Regular');        
 body {
            font-family: NotoSansCJKtc-Regular, sans-serif;
        } like this? so i dont need to use font face anymore?

Comment: Sorry is it must use require 'vendor/autoload.php'; ? because the file has not have vendor directory and what about the HTML?

Comment: based on how you installed dompdf, don't include it if u don't use composer

Comment: Sorry, the chinese text still no show, im not use the require